# Throwing cross origin error upon setting state using React hooks

Tags: reactjs, redux

The following is my hook that calls my server and fetches data. after I receive a response from the server, I'm trying to set this response to my state.

```
const [userProfileData, setUserProfileData] = useState({})    
useEffect(() => {
    const profileRequestBody = `
    query{
        GetUserAndProfileData{
            name
            email
            _id
            figsList{
                _id
                figData
                createdAt
            }
        }
    }
    `
    const usertoken = token
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/graphql',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${usertoken}`
        },
        data: {
            query: profileRequestBody
        }
    }).then(response => {
        debugger
        //check if we recieved any errors in the request
        setIsLoading(false)

        setUserProfileData(response.data.data.GetUserAndProfileData)

        let errors = response.data.errors
        console.log(errors)
        if (errors) {
            throw new Error(errors[0].message)
        }

    }).catch(err => {
        debugger
        console.log(err)

    })
}, []);
```

`setUserProfileData(response.data.data.GetUserAndProfileData)` is throwing the following error `A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.` I'm actually setting state there.

Comment: Are you using codesandbox?

Comment: @rzwnahmd no, this is from my project

Answer (score 0):

The issues is not about

`setUserProfileData(response.data.data.GetUserAndProfileData)`

when `A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.` occur, this is because when you render the data in view are in object format instead of the primitive format (e.g. int, string, float), I can give you a example

Data json format:

```
[
   {
      "name":"micky",
      "age":29,
      "sex":"M",
      "families":[
         {
            "name":"carol",
            "age":30,
            "sex":"F"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Code :

```
export default function (props) {
    const [data, setData] = React.useState([]);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        FamilyService.getdata().then(res => {
            setData(res);
        });
    }, []);
    const getdata = (row) =>{
        var familymember = row.families.find(x => x.name.includes("carol"));
        return familymember;
    }
    return (
        <div>
           {data.map((row, idx) => (
                <span>{row.name}</span>
                <span>{row.age}</span>
                <span>{getdata(row)}</span>
           ))}
        </div>
    );
}
```

In above code

```
var familymember = row.find(x => x.families.includes("data"));
return familymember; <----- This code will cause error!!!!
```

Because it is return a object instead of a value, if I want to fix the error, it should use

```
return familymember.name;
```